# How could I find patterns of repeating pairs of integers in an array or list of integers?

Tags: python, arrays, list, pattern-matching

I have below like array or list:

```
A=[2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,1,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1,1,-1,2,-1,2,-1,2,-1]
```

I need to find the repeating (2,-1) pattern sequence, if this pattern is successive,then report the successive sequence till it break off, i.e. output `B` as below

```
B=[[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1],[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1],
[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]]
```

The first `(2,-1)` pattern sequence is `[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]`, then break;
The 2nd `(2,-1)` pattern sequence is `[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]`, then break;
The last `(2,-1)` pattern sequence is also `[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]`, and break;

What is the best way to get this result?

Please note that using `(2,-1)` is an example - I'd like to be able to do this for an arbitrary pair of integers (e.g. `(3,-1`) or `(3,4)`.

Comment: where is your attempts?

Comment: @astrosyam I have tried a very long solution, the code is about 70 lines

Comment: You need to explain your special pattern more clearly. Are you just looking for repeating sequences of `2, -1`?

Comment: @VigneshKalai not fixed, and also others similar pattern, like 3,-1,3,-1 and so on

Comment: You need to **define** what kind of patterns you are looking for in exact terms. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @PM2Ring I try to find repeating 2,-1 pattern, if this pattern is successive,then report the successive sequence till it break off.

Comment: Is the base unit of your patterns always exactly two items?

Comment: What result would you expect for `A=[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4]`?

Comment: @PM2Ring Currently, the repeating-pattern is exactly two items,like (2,-1), (3,-1) and so on.

Comment: @PM2Ring I want to get: if use (2,1) , I want [[2,1,2,1]]; if use (1,2), want  [[1,2,1,2,1,2]]; if use (3,4),want [[3,4,3,4]]

Comment: @ChrinideWu I've added the info from your clarifying comments to the question.  Can you paste what you've tried into the question, too?  If it really is too long, you could paste it into a repository somewhere (e.g. dpaste.com or pastebin) and link to it, ideally pulling out the main logic and putting it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for B to contain a list of all patterns in A that begin on integer x (default at 2), end on integer y (default at -1), and alternate between the values x and y, then here's how you can generate B:

```
def special_pattern(A, x=2, y=-1):
    B = []
    temp = []
    flag = 0
    for elem in A:
        if elem == x and flag == 0:
            flag = 1
        elif elem == y and flag == 1:
            temp.extend([x, y])
            flag = 0
        else:
            if temp != []:
                B.append(temp)
                temp = []
            if not(elem == x and flag == 1): 
                flag = 0
    if temp != []:
        B.append(temp)
    return B
```

Comment: Very good code, thanks so much for your sharing and help! my solution is very interminable & ugly. you have used only 19 lines code, my code is up to 70 lines.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution:

```
def find_patterns (lst, pattern):
    pattern = list(pattern)
    patternLength = len(pattern)
    lengths = []
    i, currentLength = 0, 0
    while i <= len(lst) - patternLength:
        if lst[i:i + patternLength] == pattern:
            currentLength += 1
            i += patternLength
        else:
            i += 1
            if currentLength > 0:
                lengths.append(currentLength)
                currentLength = 0
    if currentLength > 0:
        lengths.append(currentLength)
    return [pattern * x for x in lengths]
```

It works by iterating *once* through the list and matching the pattern as long as possible. Instead of storing the actual contents of the part, it just stores the *length* of each subsequent part. Since we are looking for repetitions of the pattern, we can completely construct the repeated pattern at the very end.

The way it works, it also allows for arbitrary length patterns, and is not restricted to 2-element patterns.

Used, it looks like this:

```
>>> find_patterns([2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2, -1], (2, -1))
[[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1], [2, -1, 2, -1], [2, -1]]
>>> find_patterns([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], (1, 2))
[[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]]
>>> find_patterns([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], (1, 2, 3))
[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

If you are a fan of crazy one-liners, you can also look at this solution using regular expressions. I do not recommend it, since it’s not only barely readable but also not really efficient. It also supports arbitrary length patterns, but it also requires that the list is a list of integers, while the above solution can work with any kinds of lists. So this is really just for the curious mind:

```
def find_patterns (lst, pattern):
    return [[int(x) for x in m.split(';')] for m in re.findall('({0}(?:;{0})*)'.format(';'.join(map(str, pattern))), ';'.join(map(str, lst)))]
```

Comment: Thanks for you sharing, this code is a more general solution, very perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i didn't understand you correctly. Hope code below suits your needs:

```
A=[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]
B=[[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1],[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1],
[2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -1]]

A_str = ''.join(str(x) for x in A)
for item in B:
    if ''.join(str(x) for x in item) in A_str:
        print item
```

Comment: Surely the problem with this answer is that you have to have the output (`B`) already before the program works!